# Sveltekit +page.server.ts cannot reach backend on same machine

Tags: typescript, frontend, svelte, sveltekit, web-frontend

I have a backend server in GO running on `localhost:8081` exposing a couple of endpoints. These endpoints are nicely reachable with requests via CURL, Postman, ...

I am trying to build a SvelteKit frontend application running on dev default port `localhost:5137`. In the `+page.server.ts` file I have a load function trying to contact one of the endpoints on `localhost:8081`, but it does not work. I only ever get this error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    ...
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8081
  }
```

The contents of my `+page.server.svelte` - load function looks like this:

```
export async function load({fetch}) {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/...');
    return await res.json();
}
```

Even checked and added the missing origin headers inside the hooks.server.svelte file:

```
export const handleFetch: HandleFetch = async({request, fetch, event}) => {
    request.headers.set('Origin', event.url.origin);
    return fetch(request)
};
```

But I cannot seem to get rid of this error. Other endpoints from external public apis work nicely and I can retrieve data from them.

If anyone has any ideas, those would be greatly appreciated. I am all googled out...

---

Here is the list of used dependencies:

- NPM v9.6.4
- node v16.13.0
- "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
- "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.5.0",
- "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.0",
- "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.0",
- "eslint": "^8.28.0",
- "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
- "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
- "prettier": "^2.8.0",
- "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.8.1",
- "svelte": "^3.54.0",
- "svelte-check": "^3.0.1",
- "tslib": "^2.4.1",
- "typescript": "^4.9.3",
- "vite": "^4.0.0",
- "vitest": "^0.25.3"

I was expecting the endpoint to be reachable like any other external public API and return the expected data so I also:

- checked various CORS settings
- added missing headers

Comment: What it does say if you try to connect to the port using telnet command like `telnet 127.0.0.1 8081`

Comment: Are you using any deployment technology like Docker, Virtual Machines, etc?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa as i mentioned that using CURL or any other means of requesting the endpoint just returns the expected data. So the endpoint works as expected.

Comment: @carlosV2 no everything is being run from the console. No docker, no other deployments. Go server uses its executable and sveltkit uses the default vite dev server.

Comment: I'm really puzzled with this behaviour... I only have 3 suggestions to make: first one is to try to create an small repo were you can replicate the issue and share it for us to check. The other suggestion is to try to connect from an standalone script (to discard the possibility of being NodeJS's fault somehow). Finally, try by removing the `node_modules` folder and recreate it (npm install). This should not have any difference but I've seen some people having very weird errors being fixed with this lately so, worth a try.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for pointing me into that direction @carlosV2. removing `node_modules`, updating node and npm versions and re-installing seemed to do the trick. It does work now.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to get it to work, with @carloV2 pointing me in the right direction.

I still don't understand what the problem was, but the solution was updating node to the latest version and re-installing the node_modules. After that everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Upgrading to the latest version of Node fixed the problem.